# binary file fread/fwrite and calloc/free memory leak?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm trying to process some rather big binary files (up to 20gb per file). To do so, I want to read them in chunks, process and write to the new file.

To read the file, I use:

```
fp = fopen(filename,"rb"); //open binary file to read
fseek(fp, start_of_chunk, SEEK_SET); //set cursor to current chunk
fread(data,size_of_chunk,1,fp); //read one chunk of data
fclose(fp);
```

I then allocate some arrays using calloc and process the data.
To write it back, I use:

```
fout = fopen(file_out,"ab"); //open output binary file in append mode
fwrite(processed_data,size_of_processed_data,1,fout);
fclose(fout);
```

At the end, I use free() on each of the allocated variables (biggest one is the read data chunk (~400 MB), smallest one is about 1kB) and start all over with reading the next chunk.

The output works fine but the process keeps up eating memory like there's no tomorrow. An 800 MB test file eats up to 6 GB of RAM, rising steadily. Reading the whole file at once uses pretty much the same amount of memory as reading the chunks. Using free() between the loops releases not even 5% of the used memory even though those variables contain 99% of the data.

As I am pretty new to C programming, is there anything I might be missing? I read in another thread that the OS (Windows 10 x64 in my case, same problem on Windows 7 x64) might be too slow to release memory. Reading bigger chunks did not help in my case. All the file handles are closed after reading/writing and all allocated arrays are freed at the end.

Edit: I am allocating multiple times within the loop. I'm using

```
free(data);
data = (uint16_t*)calloc(number_of_elements,sizeof(uint16_t));
```

before each call to read data. To process a certain part of the chunk, I'm using

```
data_part = (uint16_t*)calloc(number_of_elements,sizeof(uint16_t));
memmove(data_part,pointer_to_part_of_chunk, size_of_data_part);
```

Edit 2: I changed some stuff, thanks to the comments. Still, memory load keeps rising steadily (tho slower than before). Here's the code once again:

```
//initiate variables
//allocate arrays
data = (uint16_t*)calloc(number_of_elements,sizeof(uint16_t));
array1 = (uint16_t*)calloc(number_of_elements1,sizeof(uint16_t));
array2 = (uint16_t*)calloc(number_of_elements2,sizeof(uint16_t)); //and so on

//some precalculations

//start of the loop
while (not_end_of_the_file){
    fp = fopen(filename,"rb"); //open binary file to read
    fseek(fp, start_of_chunk, SEEK_SET); //set cursor to current chunk
    fread(data,size_of_chunk,1,fp); //read one chunk of data
    fclose(fp);

    //calculate stuff
    start_of_chunk = start_of_chunk + increment;
    for (i=0;i<I;i++){
        memmove(array1,pointer_to_part_of_data, size_of_array1);
        if (statement){
            subfunction1(array1);
        }
        else{
            subfunction2(array1);
        }; //nothing more than some for loops, if statements and arithmetic operations
    //NO further allocations here, all buffers will be reused
    };

    //write result
    fout = fopen(file_out,"ab"); //open output binary file in append mode
    fwrite(processed_data,size_of_processed_data,1,fout);
    fclose(fout);
};
```

There's some allocating happening in the subfunctions but that memory should be freed after the subfunction is done, shouldn't it?

Comment: We need to see more of the code. It sounds like you may be allocated the memory repeatedly in the loop, rather than just once and reusing it.

Comment: Pretty sure that you've done something wrong in the code you haven't shown us. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Barmar I am indeed allocating repeatedly. I'll try to add some more code.

Comment: The edit doesn't help. You're asking us to examine an elephant through a microscope.

Comment: why dont you reuse the buffer instead of allocating again and again? just allocate a big enough buffer once then keep track of how much you use of it (number_of_elements*sizeof(uint16_t)), allocating is an expensive operation.

Comment: @CyberSpock Thanks, I changed that. The memory usage rises slower now. Still, it should actually only overwrite existing values during the loops and by that not occupy more memory after each loop iteration. :/

Comment: NotRelatedToTheBug: there is no real reason for using extremely large buffers. A reasonable buffer size (a few K or a few M) works just as well. In top(or vmstat) just look at the number of systemcalls/context switches and the ratio user/sys. The filesystem will typically do readahead, anyway.

Comment: *"There's some allocating happening in the subfunctions but that memory should be freed after the subfunction is done, shouldn't it?*" No, memory obtained from `malloc` and friends is never freed automatically. If you don't `free` it, it stays in memory until the program exits. I think you're used to a language that has garbage collection, like Java. C does not have garbage collection.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for the clarification. I removed all allocations I could and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
free(data);
data = (uint16_t*)calloc(number_of_elements,sizeof(uint16_t));
```

Are you sure the value of `data` in the free line is the value returned from the previous call to calloc? If it's `NULL` when you call free, that is a no-op.

Comment: No, I'm not. I wasnt aware that this could be something different then the allocated value from before. I did remove the free calls now though and shifted all allocations to happen outside the loop (see latest edit). Still, the memory usage keeps increasing during the calculations even though it should only overwrite existing arrays.